# Move logic from adapter to fragment - ERROR: Cannot find view ID's

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

**PROBLEM:** Im trying to merge my mediaplayer methods (which is inside my adapter) to my fragment(where i want to have my mediaplayer objects).
**Why?** - Because i want that my adapter should **NOT** contain any methods/logic. It should **ONLY** inflate views and nothing else.

I tried to move my MediaPlayer methods (which is inside my adapter) to my fragment but when i try to find my playB and stopB inside my fragment (which is supposed to play and stop the song) it gives me a nullexception. I looked at my XML file (where my playB + stopB ID is) and everything was ok.

**My adapter:**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//Create variables
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Song currentSong;
int layout;
ArrayList<Song> arrayList;
Context context;

//Constructor
public ListViewAdapter(int layout, ArrayList<Song> arrayList, Context context) {
    this.layout = layout;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

//ViewHolder class holding my views
private class Viewholder {
    TextView artistTxt, songNameTxt;
    ImageView playB, stopB;
    CircleImageView artistImg;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Create viewholder variable
    final Viewholder viewholder;

    //Check if view is null
    if (view == null) {

        //Create new ViewHolder object
        viewholder = new Viewholder();

        //Inflate my view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_customlayout, null);

        //Find my view id's
        viewholder.artistImg = view.findViewById(R.id.artistImgBackgroundDetail);
        viewholder.artistTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.artistTxt);
        viewholder.songNameTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.songNameTxt);
        viewholder.playB = view.findViewById(R.id.playB);
        viewholder.stopB = view.findViewById(R.id.stopB);

        //Set my view to viewholder
        view.setTag(viewholder);
    } else {
        viewholder = (Viewholder) view.getTag();
    }

    //Assign song to my arraylist
    final Song song = arrayList.get(position);

    //Set my views to their resources
    viewholder.artistImg.setImageResource(song.getArtistImg());
    viewholder.artistTxt.setText(song.getArtist());
    viewholder.songNameTxt.setText(song.getSongName());

    return view;
```

As you can see - very simple adapter where i adapt my custom listview.

**This is my fragment class where i **cannot** find view ID's:**

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Song currentSong;
int position;
ImageView playB, stopB;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    //Actionbar
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Song list");

    //Find my listview
    songListView = view.findViewById(R.id.songListView);
    playB = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.playB);
    stopB = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stopB);

    //create a new arraylist object
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(R.layout.listview_customlayout, arrayList, getActivity());

    //Set my listview to my custom adapter
    songListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Click on a specific song from my list
    songListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewClickListener());


    final Song song = arrayList.get(position);


    //get all songs
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), song.getSong());

    //Play button click performed
    playB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            //Checks if my current song is null and creates a new song
            if (currentSong == null) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), song.getSong());
            }

            //if mediaplayer is not null and my current song is not equal to the new song i clicked on
            if (mediaPlayer != null && currentSong != song) {

                //resets the mediaplayer and creates a new song from the position in the list
                mediaPlayer.reset();

                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), song.getSong());
                playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_orange);

                mediaPlayer.start();
                playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_orange);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_orange);
            }

            //check if current song is null or the newly clicked song is equal to my current song
            //if true then assign the newly clicked song as my CURRENT one
            //--so it doesnt play the same song for every single one
            if (currentSong == null || song != currentSong) {
                currentSong = song;
            }
        }
    });

    //Stop song when click performed
    stopB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //stops my current song and make it null
            if (currentSong != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();

                currentSong = null;
                playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_orange);
            }
        }
    });


    //return my view
    return view;
```

I want to leave my `ListViewAdapter` to *only inflate views* so that means that i **must not** contain funcionalitities.

Any suggestion is appreciated as im trying to better at what im doing :)

If you need additional informations please tell me. I'll gladly try to make it clear as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean

Comment: Sorry for the inconvience. I edited now.

Comment: mean you want to pass mediaplayer instance from fragment to adapter?

Comment: No. Quite the opposite. I tried to move mediaplayer objects from adapter to fragment but i keep getting nullexceptions when i try to find view id's for my `playB`

Comment: sometimes it's possible by interface, the null pointer error is because the id stopB is not initialised yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this
Make an interface

> ClickUpdate.java

```
public interface ClickUpdate {
    void getClicks();
}
```

Inside

> ListViewAdapter.java

```
public static ClickUpdate clickupadte;
public static void setonConnectionListener(ClickUpdate clicklisten) {
            ListViewAdapter.clickupadte = clicklisten
        }
```

Also give click for stopB inside listviewadapter

```
viewholder.stopB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickupadte.getClicks();
            }
        });
```

Then at last inside

> fragment class
>   inside oncreateview initialise

```
ListViewAdapter.setonConnectionListener(this);
```

also implementents ClickUpdate, then an overridden methods generate inside the fragment class with name getClicks i think inside that method give

```
 if (currentSong != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();

            currentSong = null;
            //playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_orange);//this will  cause null point error,if occured to avoid the error pass viewholder.playB inside clickupadte.getClicks(); function
        }
```

Comment: I didnt get the last part sorry

Comment: @Delice mean an overridden methods will generate their you paste mediaplayer.stop() etc that code

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM pattern, adapters are supposed to be associated with the view rather than the View Model. So what you could potentially do is make the adapter an inner class of the fragment class. If you have the mediaPlayer a global variable, you can use the same instance of it inside the adapter and the fragment, if that is what you are looking for.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I rather stay a way from MVVM pattern as it is more complex and i need to change my whole project architecture but thanks for the input!